# How dose Pyside6 Signal emit transfer data? For dictionary data, why the behavior different?

Tags: pyside, pyside6

During the usage of Pyside6 Signal, I find there's some difference when Signal emit dictionary data:

Below is my code:

```python
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QThread, Signal
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MyThread(QThread):
    my_signal = Signal(dict)
    # my_signal = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.my_signal.emit(
            # {1: "Hello"},
            {"name": "John", "age": 30},)
        # self.my_signal.emit("Hello from MyThread!")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.my_signal.connect(self.my_slot)

        self.thread.start()

    def my_slot(self, message):
        print(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

As you can see, if emit dictionary data with {"name": "John", "age": 30}, then my_slot function could get the message correct. But if I use dictionary data which key is int number: {1: "Hello"}, then my_slot function can only get empty dictionary data: {}

I wonder why the behavior is different? Thanks.

I use Pyside2 instead, and it could get dictionary data normally.

Comment: It's a bug in PySide6. A work-around is to use `my_signal = Signal(object)`. Generally speaking, both PySide and PyQt should try to convert to and from a C++ type when sending signals. For a `dict`, the corresponding type would be a `QMap` - but that will only work if *all* the keys are strings; otherwise, a pointer to the `dict` must be sent instead, and no implicit copying will be done. Clearly, PySide6 is currently failing to handle this latter case correctly.

Comment: PS: the specifc reason *why* the `dict` keys must be strings is because, internally, PySide/PyQt uses a [pre-defined alias](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvariant.html#QVariantMap-typedef) for `QMap<QString, QVariant>`. Strictly speaking, `QMap` is much more flexible than that, but it relies on a C++ language feature than isn't available in Python.

Comment: Thanks for your help, use object instead can work normally now.  And it seems Pyside2 can work without this problem, is there any difference during the QMap usage? Or it cover different situations?

Comment: The benefit of using `QMap` is that it serialises the data, which ensures thread-safety (since every signal emits a unique copy of the data). This means that, no matter which version of PySide (or PyQt) you use, sending a `dict` with non-string keys is *never guaranteed to be thread-safe* (since a pointer will be emitted, rather than a copy of the data). However, this is only a problem in situations where multiple threads can read/write from the same data at the same time (in which case, it might be necessary to use mutexes). The example in your question doesn't have that problem, though.